# What is the difference between $promise and $q promises in angular1.x?

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-resource

I started using promises in angular for resolving my api calls with the following syntax:

```
 $scope.module = moduleFactory.get({id: $stateParams.id})
    .$promise.then(function(response){
        $scope.module = response;
     }
```

Now, I have encountered a situation where I have to chain multiple promises in a for loop and execute some code once all the promises in the for loop have been resolved. I have been trying to search for how to do this with the $promise syntax, but most sources on the internet talk about $q. I am new into development work and am finding it very confusing to juggle between these two concepts ($q and $promise). Request you nice folks to: first, explain to me the difference between $promise and $q; second, if I decide to use $q for solving my present problem as described above, does it mean I will have to rewrite the code that used $promise in order to make it chainable with something like $q.all()?

Comment: Short answer: `$promise` is a property on the return value of certain operations which returns a promise for the result of that operation. `$q` is a service which provides some promise creation and manipulation mechanisms like `$q.all` and `$q.resolve`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can construct a promise in angular by calling `$q`:

```
 let promise = $q(function(resolve, reject) { ... };
```

or if you simply want a promise that resolves immediately:

```
 let promise = $q.resolve(somevalue);
```

There is also an older way using `$q.defer()` to construct a deferred object and returning it's `.promise` attribute, but you should probably avoid doing it that way and consider it just for backward compatibility.

The final way to create a new promise is to call `.then()` (or `.catch()`) on an existing promise.

The `.$promise` attribute is simply a promise created by one of the above mechanisms either by the `$resource` service or by something following the same pattern.

Once you have some promises you can stuff them all into an array and use `$q.all()` to wait for them all to complete, or for one to reject. Or if you want things to happen sequentially you can chain them together by performing each step in the `.then()` of the previous promise:

```
 let promise = $q.resolve();
 for(... something ...) {
     promise = promise.then(() => { ... next step here ...});
 }
 promise.then(() => { ... runs when everything completed ...});
```

That will execute everything in sequence whereas `$q.all()` starts them off in parallel. Sometimes you want one, sometimes the other:

```
 let promises = [];
 for(... something ...) {
     promises.push(somethingThatReturnsAPromise());
 }
 $q.all(promises).then(() => { ... runs when everything completed ...});
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer :)

Answer (score 7):

`$promise` is a property of objects returned by the [$resource Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) class-type action methods.

> It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.
>
> The Resource instances and collections have these additional properties:
>
> - `$promise`: the promise of the original server interaction that created this instance or collection.
>
>   On success, the [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) is resolved with the same resource instance or collection object, updated with data from server. This makes it easy to use in [resolve section of $routeProvider.when()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) to defer view rendering until the resource(s) are loaded.
>
>   On failure, the promise is rejected with the [http response](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) object, without the resource property.
>
> [--AngularJS $resource Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

---

**Note:** The example code in the question is redundant and unnecessary.

```
$scope.module = moduleFactory.get({id: $stateParams.id})
    .$promise.then(function(response){
        //REDUNDANT, not necessary
        //$scope.module = response;
    });
```

The assignment of resolved responses to $scope is not necesssary as the [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) will automatically populate the reference when the results come from the server. Use the [$promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) property only when code needs to work with results *after* they come from the server.

To distinguish services which return [$resource Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) objects from other services which return promises, look for a `.then` method. If the object has a `.then` method, it is a promise. If it has a `$promise` property, it follows the [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) pattern.

---

---

*It must be obvious to you, but I used an array of $resource.$promise's inside [$q.all()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) and it worked.*

[$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) works with promises from any source. Under the hood, it uses [$q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) to convert values or promises (any then-able object) to [$q Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) promises.

What sets [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) apart from the `all` method in other promise libraries is that in addition to working with arrays, it works with JavaScript objects that have properties that are promises. One can make a hash (associative array) of promises and use [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) to resolve it.

```
var resourceArray = resourceService.query(example);

var hashPromise = resourceArray.$promise.then(function(rArray) {
    promiseHash = {};
    angular.forEach(rArray,function (r) {
        var item = resourceService.get(r.itemName);
        promiseHash[r.itemName] = item.$promise;
    });
    //RETURN q.all promise to chain
    return $q.all(promiseHash);
});

hashPromise.then(function (itemHash) {
    console.log(itemHash);
    //Do more work here
});
```

The above example creates a hash of items indexed by itemName with all the items being fetched asynchronously from a [$resource Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Comment: This is really helpful. It must be obvious to you, but I used an array of $resource.$promise's inside $q.all() and it worked. Your answer helped me strengthen my conceptual understanding. Thanks :)